# Django postgres migration error foreign key constraint does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using a PostgreSQL database hosted with aws, everytime I try to migrate (`python manage.py migrate`) I run into this error: `column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`.

I have tried removing the two foreign keys that I'm using with no luck I still get the same error. I have also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898908/what-wrong-with-my-models-py) with no luck. The rest migrates with no problem, Just this one error

**Model.py**

```
class Subprogram(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    budget = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=0, max_digits=11)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    budget = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=11)
    budget_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=current_year(), validators=[MinValueValidator(current_year)])
    file = models.FileField(blank=True)
    subprogram = models.ForeignKey(Subprogram, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Program(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def overall_budget(self):
        all_projects = self.subprogram_set.all()
        total = 0
        for project in all_projects:
            total += project.budget
        return total

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('program-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: Is there a default value for `Project.subprogram`? And can you sahre the `Program` model?

Comment: @schillingt updated, I have provided the program model :)

Comment: @schillingt Also, no I was testing to see if setting default=0 would solve it

Comment: Please open up a database shell via `python manage.py dbshell` or `psql`. Then check the three tables to make sure they all have `id` columns. The command is `\d <table_name>`

Comment: @schillingt All have id column except for `Project`. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes. The error sounds like you have a model that references the Project model. That means you're trying to create a foreign key to a column that doesn't exist. If you don't have any data, I'd rebuild all the migrations. If you do, then, you'll need to add the column manually in a migration or in the database itself.

Comment: @schillingt I did this and now I'm getting this error... any idea? `there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "home_project"`

Comment: It sounds like your database is out of sync with your migrations. If you're dealing with only test and/or development data, I would start over. If not, then you need to figure out which unique constraint it's referencing and create it on the database.

Comment: @schillingt I dropped the database, created a new one & ran `makemigrations` again but I still get the same error when running 'migrate'. It works if I use the local `sqlite3` database that defaults to django.

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` with no existing migrations?

Comment: That was it, you got it. Legend